# Visual Studio Crashing when I am using a certain solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, crash

Whenever I open a solution for Project A it works for a little while(time varies) then the window freezes and eventually crashes. However when I open Project B I can work on it all day and it works fine.

Exception Information
Code: 0xe053534f   Flags: 0x00000000
Record: 0x0000000000000000    Address: 0x000000007c812afb

Error Signature
AppName: devenv.exe AppVer: 9.0.30729.1 AppStamp: 488f2b50
ModName: kernel32.dll  ModVer: 5.1.2600.5781   ModStamp: 49c4f482
fDebug: 0 Offset: 00012afb

I know this probably means nothing, just let me know what information is needed and I will include it. Also I have tried "Clean solution" to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**:
Projects are both C# .net 3.5 Applications. I run them both in Visual Studio 2008. Addins used are Regionerate, Rockscroll, SmartPaster and Resharper 5

Only cause/effect noticed is when I go to my web browser(or any other window) if some time has passed VS is frozen and crashing a while after clicking in the window.

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question but are both solutions about the same size/language/etc.  Also, do you have any plugins/extensions to visual studio installed?

Comment: Both solutions are C# .net 3.5, around the same size. Add-ins used are Regionerate, RockScroll, Smart Paster 2008 and of course Resharper 5

Comment: Is project A a web project with a large JS library included in it by any chance?  If so then I've experienced a similar problem with VS2008 JS autocomplete choking on large JS libraries (jqGrid).  Also, you should add information about project size and plugins into the question (no point making people hunt through the comments to get all the relevant information).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Code: 0xe053534f

The last 3 hex codes translate to 'SSO'.  Which is an acronym for Soft Stack Overflow.  Always fun when the error code matches the web site name.  A soft stack overflow exception is raised when the runtime detects that a hard stack overflow is imminent when it is setting up a call stack.  It is a serious error, just a wee bit less disastrous as getting a hard stack overflow.

It is almost certainly caused by an unholy interaction between the add-ons you are using.  Disable them one-by-one to find the trouble-maker.

Comment: Turned out being Resharper. I unistalled and it worked, then reinstalled and it didn't. So I deleted the Resharper files inside my project and everythings fine.

Answer (score 1):

How big is the project?

If it's not too big, it might be worth your while creating a new project and progressively transferring your code across, to see if you can work out where the problem is. Just recreating the project might resolve the problem.

Have you observed any cause/effect - is it when you open a particular code file, for example? Or in the Designer?

And as R0MANARMY hints at in his comment, try starting VS in [safemode](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/27/vs-2008-compatibility-with-older-vs-2005-add-in-packages.aspx).

Comment: The only cause/effect I have noticed is that it only seems to happen when I use the browser then switch back to VS. I click on the window and its frozen. Note I have more then one screen and VS is always shown.

Comment: @Gage, I remember having problems at one point, which I [attributed to rockscroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464751/class-member-order-in-source-code/464769#464769), but since then I've reinstalled it, and no further problems. As I said, try safe mode, then try removing some add-ins.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the hidden [.suo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909%28VS.80%29.aspx) file of the solution.

It happened to me this file was corrupted for some reasons and prevented me to open my solution.