# Protected method in UML diagram?

Tags: c++, uml, public, class-diagram, protected

I have the following UML showing how to create a class `Point2D`.

[image]

I have created a header file for this class based on the UML:

```
#ifndef Point2D_h
#define Point2D_h

using namespace std;

// Header file for class Point2D

class Point2D
{
    protected:
        int x;
        int y;
        double distFrOrigin;
        setDistFrOrigin();
    
    public:
        Point2D()
        {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }

        Point2D(int xInput, int yInput)
        {
            x = xInput;
            y = yInput;
        }

        int getX();
        int getY();
        double getScalarValue();
    
        int setX(int x);
        int setY(int y);    
};

#endif
```

However, I am confuse on the method `setDistFrOrigin()`. The method is located inside the UML operation and it is a protected method. Am I suppose to group it with the `protected` in my class? Or is there a way to declare protected in the public block in the class? What should be the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Total freedom

C++ gives you total freedom for this.  You may for example:

- group the members by [access specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access). You could inside a section optically group variables and functions;
- group the members à-la UML, with variables on one side and functions on the other, having each time a `private`, `protected` and `public` section.

### Additional remarks

- Style is a matter of personal taste and [being consistent is more important](https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#layout-style) than chosen style. Therefore in a team always adopt the team's style.
- Keep in mind, that someone will have to maintain the code and an access specifier might be easily overlooked when scrolling back and forth. 3 or 4 sections are manageable.  If you have 6 sections,  or even 12 in case of static members, it starts to become hard to read.
- This other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/308581/3723423) is more general about ordering of members.  It shows that there are many opinions, and that besides data and functions, there are also constants and types.
- A widely accepted recommendation is to put the `public` part fist (see Bruno's comment + [C++ Core Guideline](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c9-minimize-exposure-of-members), [Google coding standards](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Declaration_Order), and [similar style guide](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#coding-std-wars)).  Nevertheless, if you've learned C++ with Stroustrup's older books, you wouldn't be shocked to have all the private data then functions at the beginning,  and only a public keyword in the middle of the class followed by mostly functions, which is not so far from the UML layout)

### Not related:

- The C++ core guidelines recommend to have [no protected data](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rh-protected).  They don't tell, but it is correlated with a high risk of infringing the history constraint of [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).
- On a more positive note,  at least your design respects the principle that all [non-const data members of a class should have same access level](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c134-ensure-all-non-const-data-members-have-the-same-access-level).  Applying this principle has btw the effect of reducing the number of sections and making the second approach much more readable ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Understood - my way of doing it is fine then!

Comment: @user3118602 yes: it's simple and has the advantage of visually separating the public part that everybody can use, and the more restricted parts which are about the class internals.

Comment: @user3118602 is you read better than nice answer you can see that to improve readability / maintainability is it better to separate the attributes and operations => add an empty line then a `protected:` before the declaration of `setDistFrOrigin();`, and move the public part before the protected one (we read from top to bottom)

Comment: @bruno thanks for the suggestion.  I've adressed that point with adding some further references and underlining pros and cons.